# Examining Page Using ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, process, load, hide

I am trying to build a website where the user enters a URL in a form and then another page that receives the URL examines the page to which the URL points without showing it to the user. However, I cannot figure out how to get at the contents of a page using ASP (js version). The location.assign method does not seem to work in ASP. Is this because the receiver page is not a real website (it does not have html headers) or is it because that method cannot be used?

Comment: This is your second question where you are nothing showing any code and are beeing vague vague about your exact problem. What have you tried? You seem to be looking for someone to write all of your code.

Comment: I do not expect people to write my code for me. That was very rude.

Comment: Well, then show the code your working on. By showing the code, we can help you better and you get better answers.

Comment: @GuidoGautier: unfortunately SO has entered the phase of life that there are plenty of users willing to respond to this sort of question.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones as a new StackOverflow user, I sadly came to the same realization.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of a remote webpage in your server-side code using the ServerXMLHTTP object.

```
<% 
    url = Request("url")
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
    xmlhttp.send "" 

    response = xmlhttp.responseText 

    ' Do something with the response here

    set xmlhttp = nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Was this using VBSCRIPT or JAVASCRIPT? If it was in VBSCRIPT, do you have the JAVASCRIPT version?

Comment: This is using VBScript.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. Are you saying your classic ASP page is using JavaScript on the server side? Or are you asking for an AJAX solution?

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but it is my understanding that you can use different languages with ASP, one of which is javascript. I am trying to use the javascript version. If this involves ajax, then, yes, I want to use ajax.

Comment: Aah, that makes more sense! JScript is on of the scripting languages you can use to write Server Side ASP Classic. You are looking for Client Side JavaScript. Maybe you could update your question to make this clear. I can re-tag it afterwards, so it is visible in the JavaScript section.

Comment: Okay, so I kind of have things working. I got the data, now I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate it in ways other than just writing it. The information that I found was in VB, but, by changing some things, it is now in the JS version of ASP. I will paste the code. My question now is if there is any kind of fairly straight forward documentation on the Microsoft XMLHttp component.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Language=JAVAScript %>
<%
var p1 = Request.QueryString('geturl')+'';
Response.Buffer = true;
var xml;
xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xml.Open("GET", "http://shop.safeway.com/", false);
xml.Send();
Response.Write("<h1>The HTML Output</h1>");
Response.Write(xml.responseText);
%>
```

I am sorry. This was supposed to be posted yesterday. The message that said that my answer did not post did not get read by my screen reader.